# Kotlin Gradle api configuration not found

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a weird error `Configuration with name 'api' not found` in my Kotlin Gradle project.

Interesting, it works if I **don't add any sub-modules**, but as soon as I add the sub-module it starts complaining.

Here is the root build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.0"
}

buildscript {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    val kotlinterVersion = "3.13.0"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") }
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("org.jmailen.gradle:kotlinter-gradle:$kotlinterVersion")
        classpath("com.adarshr:gradle-test-logger-plugin:3.2.0")
    }
}

allprojects {
    group = "com.proj"
    version = "1.0.0"

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.preferProjectModules()
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"

    tasks.withType<JavaCompile>().configureEach {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
        options.compilerArgs.addAll(listOf("-Xlint:all", "-Xlint:-serial"))
    }

    dependencies {
        api("my-dependency")
    }

    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "java-library")
    apply(plugin = "maven-publish")
    apply(plugin = "kotlin")
    apply(plugin = "org.jmailen.kotlinter")

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile::class) {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "17"
            javaParameters = true
        }
    }

    java {
        withSourcesJar()
    }
}
```

So this alone works. But as soon as I add an empty sub-module with any build.gradle, it breaks. Here's an example of child module.

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.0"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = "https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2")
    }
}

apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")

tasks.withType<BootJar> {
    archiveFileName.set("$archiveBaseName.$archiveExtension")
}
tasks.getByName("jar").enabled = true

tasks.withType<BootRun> {
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()
}

dependencies {

}
```

But it breaks with any other sub-module too. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `"api"("my-dependency")`. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html#configurations-and-dependencies

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. What do you mean cross-configuring? I merely have a project with submodules.

Comment: You're "cross-configuring" those subprojects (i.e., you're trying to configure a subproject from another project's build file via the `subprojects` block).

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but what if you put the `dependencies` block _after_ all those `apply` calls (with or without using `"api"` instead of `api`)?

Comment: I'll be damned this worked. You sir are a genious. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you could get it to work :) You may also want to check out so-called [convention plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins) (and here's a [sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html)). It uses [`buildSrc`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources).